# Preventing files from being backed up in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an App that was rejected because I am downloading some images from the internet, and the App Store reviewer says these should not be backed up (which I strongly disagree with, but what can I do).

So, I put all of these files in a directory under /Documents, and I added the do not backup attribute to the files in the sub-directory (but forgot to do so on the sub-directory itself).

When I resubmitted my App, the app was rejected again because the reviewer said I was still using too much space, and I get the impression that my do not backup attribute was not honored.

I think I may know the problem, but I would like to get confirmation before going to the re-submit process for my App yet one more time.

Right now, my directory structure looks like:

```
Documents/
    subdir.derived/
        <a bunch of files>
```

I put the do not backup attribute on the files, but not on "subdir.derived".

When I re-read over Apple's documentation, I'm wondering if the do not backup attribute only works at the top level of the "Documents/" directory, and not on files in subdirs.

Can anyone confirm that this is true? If I add the do not backup attribute to the "subdir.derived", will that fix my problem?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Note ... thanks for the useful suggestions about the caches directory, but I feel that the images I use are critical to using my App, and according to Apple's guidelines, the caches directory should not be used for data that is critical when offline.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Library/Caches directory for downloaded images.  That's why it exists, and it is not automatically backed up, so the reviewers won't complain about it.  It also has a handy shortcut: NSCachesDirectory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply ... see the comments that I added to the answer from #picciano

Answer (score 3):

When we got a similar rejection note, we moved all our cache files from `~/Documents` to `~/Library/PrivateDocuments` and set the do-not-backup flag on the `PrivateDocuments` directory. That was enough to please App Store reviewers.

Why not `~/Library/Caches`? Although the files are *technically* a cache, our users are expected to be able to access them while offline. Since `~/Library/Caches` may be cleared without notice by the OS, our users may unexpectedly find that the content they did bother to download for offline access has disappeared.

The directory name `PrivateDocuments` was explicitly suggested by the App Store reviewer, by the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I'll try one more time to see if that satisfies the approver.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the app's temp directory for cached files that can otherwise be recreated. The temp directory will not get backed up and may be deleted by iOS as it sees fit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I could use the "caches" directory, although the images are part of a study app, and they should never be deleted. In my mind, they should also be backed up (which Apple disagrees with). Imagine that you are studying medicine, and have a study set with a bunch of images of things you are studying. In the caches directory, these images could spontaneously disappear in low storage situations and then you would no longer be able to study.

Comment: Just one more comment ... the reason why I feel they should also be backed up is the images are ones that the user searches for and chooses to study. I can save a pointer to the image's location, but if the user restores their device or upgrades their device, these images may no longer exist, and their study sets will become useless.

Comment: Working with the App store can be SOOO frustrating. No one to talk to, and very little feedback from the reviewers. Just "Rejected". Sigh!!!

Comment: No argument there...have you tried explaining that in the "reviewers notes" box in iTunesConnect?

Comment: I've tried and the only response I received was "please contact developer technical support for technical issues". But its not a technical issue!!! (another sigh! :-)